# Strange line after merging two objects

Tags: subdivision-surface

I joined two objects and after merging their vertices there is a strange line when using subdivision surface modifier. I already checked for duplicates vertices and internal faces.
Anyone has an idea whats the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the face orientation is correct? - Check Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlays dropdown.

Comment: Great, thanks, that was the issue!

Comment: No problem! Well known issue.